# dot product of vectors with noncommutative elements

Tags: function-construction, simplifying-expressions, syntax, algebra

I came upon an interesting problem. Suppose you have three vectors $\psi=(a, b)$, $\phi=(c,d)$  such that  their components do not commute:
$ac\neq ca$, $bd \neq db$ etc.
(in general the vectors may have more than two components)
How do you perform the inner product `ψ.φ`?

Comment: You could use `Inner[]` with `NonCommutativeMultiply[]`...

Comment: @J.M.'sdiscontentment `Inner` allows the calculation of the inner product of only two vectors. If I need the inner product of 4 or 6?

Comment: The inner product is a scalar and can be factored out. So for e.g. 4 vectors it would read: v1.v2  v3.v4

Comment: By "." I mean any inner product you are using.

Comment: How exactly do you define the inner product of three or more vectors?

Comment: sorry, I meant to write 4 vectors, i.e : (a.b)*(c.d)

Answer (score 2):

In [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC)

```
NCDot[{a, b}, {c, d}]
```

evaluates to

> a ** c + b ** d

as you want. `NCDot` is the familiar matrix product that takes into account noncommutative entries. Another example:

```
NCDot[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {e, f}]
```

evaluates to:

> {a ** e + b ** f, c ** e + d ** f}